# How can I recover WLAN keys and preferred network list inaccessible from UI?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I've recently ran self-booting diagnostic software from DVD on my laptop. When it finished its job, I went back to Windows 7 and found out what my WLAN (Broadcom adapter based) kinda jammed - no longer displays broadcasted SSID list. I've cycled adapter admin-down and up w/o success and when fixed the problem by removing adapter's driver and letting Windows reinstate it. Now WLAN seems to be functional **but** my preferred networks list is now empty (along with keys). How can I recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html#DownloadLinks) by [Nir Sofer](http://www.nirsoft.net/) did the job. Few garbage it the list and couple of networks swapped places but otherwise it my list has been restored.